# Is this : $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\tan(n!)}$ convergent sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I'm not able to predict if the below sum if it is convergent by using some standard test , then how do i know if it is convergent or no ?
 $$S=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\tan(n!)}$$ ?

Comment: $\frac{(-1)^n}{\tan(n!)}$ does not converge to zero..

Comment: "Obviously" not, but do you have a simple proof of this, @yanko?

Comment: Do you mean, @yanko, to say $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{\tan(n!) }\neq 0\;?$$

Comment: zeraoulia  Your expression is a series.

Comment: If it were $\dfrac1{\tan(n)}$, it would be easy to see, because $\left\{\dfrac{n}{\pi}\right\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$, so that will become arbitrarily large arbitrarily often. With $n!$ instead of $n$, that's not so obvious, but true, I think. Warning:  $\left\{\dfrac{n!}{e}\right\}$ is **not** dense in $[0,1]$!

Comment: See e.g. [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45665/distribution-mod-1-of-factorial-multiples-of-real-numbers).  Bottom line: very little is known about the limiting behaviour of $\tan(n!)$.